# SQL Server Extended Event - How to reduce the fields of the event "sql_statement_completed"?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

My goal: Use SQL Extended Event to perform Audit (strictly using Standard Edition, not Enterprise)

From previous [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151453/sql-server-how-to-convert-audit-log-into-a-table), I am able to capture and view the **sql statement** logged by the Extended Event. However, the event has so many redundant fields, such that it makes the .xel file really big (around 4x the original table for 100,000 new inserts)

[image]

The image attached shows all the columns captured. As observed, there are numerous fields: attach_activity_id.guid, client_app_name, cpu_time, ... etc
I was thinking this is supposed configure-able. However, it seems that, there is no checkbox in the configure page, as shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to reduce the fields? (basically i only need client_app_name and statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say you are getting all the extra fields because you picked a template when you built your event session (or used the wizard). If you only want certain fields then go uncheck what you don't want. However, there will be some event level info that will always be there, what is shown under the "Event Fields" for each event are their by default and cannot be removed.

Default event for "sql_statement_completed" only captures this, after I checked the global field for client application name:
[image]