# SQL Audit and Truncating the Audit File

Tags: sql-server, audit

I'd like to set up SQL Audit on our SQL 2014 database and then setup a process where we read the contents of the audit file, on a periodic basis, using fn_get_audit_file() but then immediately truncate the audit file to prevent the files from accumulating and growing. I cannot find a way to truncate the audit file. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Just delete the file, or set the rollover settings to reasonable values.

Comment: I'd suggest using a relatively small rollover file size (say 10mb) and then use the technique in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151466/60085) post to periodically capture the audit data and subsequently delete the audit logs that have been processed.